# Streamlit python state not refreshing

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

Building a basic Streamlit `file-to-image display` app

It takes a `file` as `input`, converts `each_page` as `image` and then should `display` all the images, where I should be able to `select` and `view` each image that I want

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_image_select import image_select

with st.form("key1"):
    
    file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
    button_check = st.form_submit_button("Button to Click")

    if button_check:
       
       with st.spinner("processing"):
             
            with open (FILE_PATH', mode = 'wb') as w:
              w.write(file.getvalue())

            #extract each page of the file and save it as images

            page_images = ["page_1.png", "page_2.png"]
            
            img = image_select("Label", page_images)
            st.image(img, caption = img)
```

This works fine, except the last part, where I am able to see all the images, but when I `click` to select any image `view` is always the `first_image` in the list and the `click` on other images in the display does not work.

Any suggestions will be helpful